# return an unsigned char in a signal/slot mechanism in Qt

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, signals-slots

I'm using QThreads in Qt, and I'm creating a signal in the worker so it can return an `unsigned char buf[10]` to be plotted in the `gui thread`. here's my signal.

```
unsigned char Worker::newinfo(unsigned char buf[10])
{
    return buf;
}
```

what's wrong here?

in my function where the buf is received I emit the signal so it can be caught in the gui slot:

```
emit newinfo(buf);

connect(worker, SIGNAL(newinfo(unsigned char[])), this, SLOT(process_new_info(unsigned char[])));
```

it tels me there is amultiple defenition of `newinfo()`.

here's my worker class:

```
class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Worker(FILE *datafile, int sockint, int bitsint);
    ~Worker();

    FILE *data;
    int sock;
    int bits;

public slots:
    void doWork();

signals:
    void finished();
    unsigned char newinfo(unsigned char buf[10]);

private:

};
```

Comment: What's the exact error you're getting from the compiler?

Comment: `moc_gui.cpp:110: multiple definition of Worker::newinfo(unsigned char*)'`
`gui.cpp:64: first defined here`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That doesn't make sense at all. And your problem will go away if you change to `std::vector<unsigned char>` or a `QByteArray`.

Answer (score 2):

`moc_gui.cpp:110: multiple definition of Worker::newinfo(unsigned char*)' gui.cpp:64: first defined here`

Signal are not meant to be defined explicitly by the programmer, but by the moc. And when you define signals or slots, they need to be void.

It seems what you want to do can be achieved with a combination of [QtConcurrent::run()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtconcurrentrun.html) (for asynchronous execution) and a [QFutureWatcher](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfuturewatcher.html) (for asynchronous access to the result ). Look it up on SO, there are plenty of posts.

EDIT: 
First of all `return buf[10];` in the code above return the 11th element of buf which doesnt make sense as you said you have `10` elements. Second, assuming everything else is correct, transmitting a pointer in a signal is sources of defects. Either both threads may access concurrently to the same data, or the GUI may try to access the data buffer while it is not valid. And as `ypnos`, you can avert this particular issue by passing objects which can be safely transmitted between threads.

Comment: I have the thread running. the only part left is porting the informaton to the gui thread.

Comment: the signature of your signal may be `void newinfo(QByteArray buff);`. And you trigger the signal with `emit newinfo(mybuffer)`.

Comment: can the mybuffer array be a `unsigned char [10]`?

Comment: yes, it would be `return buf` only; the signal is emited after the buf is ready to be transmited.

Comment: ok, I understand I can't define signals. I don't understand how to pass buf from the worker to the gui thread.

Comment: I know I have to use signals and slots, but I don't understand how the buf can reach the gui thread. that's why I tried to create a return.

Comment: The parameter you give to the signal when you call `emit newinfo(buf)` is passed as a parameter to the connected slot.  You don't need to return anything.